# WPF ComboBox.DataContext doesn't pick up table contents where it was working in a different project before

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have the following peace of code which would fill in the a ComboBox with a list of items from a table. It works flawlessly in a previous development, but it doesn't seem to display anything in the new development. Both are connecting to the same database, everything is the same. It even got the items when I put a break point, but when it comes to displaying them the content of the ComboBox is empty. When it was used first time it was developed in Visual Studio 2013, the new is in 2015, but it shouldn't be an issue I think. Any ideas?

Code:

```
public partial class CustomerManagementWindow : Window
{
    private RaeConfigurationEntities raeContext = null;
    bool newCustomer;

    public CustomerManagementWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.raeContext = new RaeConfigurationEntities();
        countryComboBox.DataContext = this.raeContext.Countries.OrderBy(i => i.CountryDescription);
    }
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="CountryTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CountryDescription}" />
            <TextBlock Text=" : " />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=CountryName}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
<ComboBox Margin="170,152,10,0" Name="countryComboBox" 
              VerticalAlignment="Top" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CountryTemplate}" 
               />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not executing the query, so you are returning an IQueryable when what you need in this case is an IEnumerable. Invoke ToList() to force the execution of the query:

```
    countryComboBox.DataContext = this.raeContext.Countries.OrderBy(i => 
i.CountryDescription).ToList();
```

Note:
You can read data binding errors from the output windows when you are debugging.